# opt : symbol lookup error at llvm last version

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, clang, llvm

I re-install **llvm** in my pc to get the **newer version** and i follow again this tutorial [WritingAnLLVMPass](http://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.html)  .
I had already an older pass from the previous version of llvm and i add this in the newer version folder.
Until the step of **make** all went fine.When i try to use opt command to load my Pass i get this **symbol lookup error**

```
opt: symbol lookup error: ../../../Release+Asserts/lib/PassRAF.so: undefined symbol: _ZNK4llvm5Value5printERNS_11raw_ostreamEb
```

in  `errs ()` instruction in my pass(i was printing my IR code with this line)

```
errs() << *I << "\n";
```

if i comment this line i get again symbol lookup error in another line for another reason.

i didnt use cmake to my build llvm because i prefer use autotools and i follow this way [Building LLVM with autotools.](http://llvm.org/docs/BuildingLLVMWithAutotools.html)

any idea what happend with opt in the last version? Is there something i forgot to do ?

Comment: have you added enough link options to your makefile? take a look at the result of `llvm-config --libs` (since you seem building as a subproject, you need to add the correct *component*, the complete list of which can be found from the output of `llvm-config --components`).

Comment: Have you recompiled your pass against newly installed LLVM?

Comment: @HongxuChen i try both commands and i get two list of libs how can i check or re-install all  libs?

Comment: @arrowd yes i did .i get this error in the opt -load command

Comment: @strayrebel should be something like `LINK_COMPONENTS` in https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/master/tools/opt/Makefile

Comment: i downgrade the version of llvm and now i haven't this error